# Splitting CCK Node Content into Multiple Pages in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, cck, drupal-themes

I've a relatively long customized content type in Drupal that I'm trying to split across a few pages. The page has a bunch of custom CCK fields and I'd like to do something like node-name/general/, node-name/pricing/, node-name/photos, etc. What are the modules and techniques I would need to do this? I'm still a relative newbie to Drupal so I'm not sure if this is something that could be done with Views, Panels, or something else.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using views for this. Views and CCK go together very well as a set.

In views you can add a new 'page' view then based on the url to get the correct record (you use the settings Arguments for this)

You can add separate views for the different sections in your cck using the 'Page settings' path.

Although this explanation will not in itself be easy enough to get straight up and do this in views. This is the way of doing it without writing your own module. Once familiar with views it should be fairly simple though.

A good place to start with views might be [Here](http://learnbythedrop.com/drop/22)

Comment: +1 For using views, you can also easily add tabs to access the different views (fields) of the CCK content type if you want.

Comment: I understand Views for grouping content and including a few fields. But I've never used it on individual nodes. Thanks for the link, but doesn't work for me in China. No YouTube :(